# how to autofill foreach loop in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i would like to know command to autofill `foreach loop` syntax as we can do autofill for the `for loop` syntax by pressing tab key 2 time after typing for.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `Ctrl + Space` for intellisense suggestions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Type **foreach** and press the **Tab** key two times.  It works the same as what you did with the **for** loop.